# TemplateDoesNotExist at / blog/home.html, blog/post_list.html

Tags: django, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy my project on heroku but getting error:TemplateDoesNotExist at / blog/home.html, blog/post_list.html.But every thing is working fine on my local server.In 'blog' app i have 'Template' directory and inside that i have 'blog' directory which contains 'home.html'. Any suggestion,please.
Error log:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /blog/home.html, blog/post_list.html
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    https://mynextlevelapp.herokuapp.com/
    Django Version: 3.1.6
    Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
    Exception Value:blog/home.html,blog/post_list.html  
blog/home.html, blog/post_list.html 
blog/home.html, blog/post_list.html 
    blog/home.html, blog/post_list.html
    Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py, line 47, in select_template
    Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
    Python Version: 3.6.13
    Python Path:    
    ['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
     '/app',
     '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python36.zip',
     '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6',
     '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
     '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
    Server time:    Mon, 01 Mar 2021 16:03:51 +0000
```

Comment: Please add your INSTALLED_APPS and BASE_DIR from settings.py, urls.py, maybe views.py code

Answer (score 1):

Make sure in your project settings.py 'APP_DIRS': True

TEMPLATES = [
{
'APP_DIRS': True,
},
]

Otherwise it will not find your templates inside app directory. and Instead of using 'Template' as directory name, use 'templates'

Comment: settings.py has 'APP_DIRS': True and i changed directory name to 'templates,but no avail.Still it is showing error.